# how to configure proxy server in WSO2 API manager?

Tags: wso2-api-manager

[WSO2 API Manager Docs](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM190/Changing+the+Default+Transport) - this doc talks about how to setup proxy & port but nothing about the username & password required to authenticate with proxy server. Without it I get proxy authentication errors. How to provide proxy's username & password?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is well documented [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Enabling+HTTP+Basic+Authentication+through+a+Proxy+Server) for WSO2 ESB. Same applies to WSO2 API Manager as well. By following provided documentation, after configuring axis2.xml, you have to add the following properties just before the send mediator in your API synapse configuration (found at $AM_HOME/repository/deployment/server/synapse-configs/default/api/admin--Hello_v1.0.0.xml).

```xml
<property name="Proxy-Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('userName:password'))" scope="transport"/>
<property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
```

Complete API synapse configurations would be as shown below;

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
     name="admin--Hello"
     context="/hello"
     version="1.0.0"
     version-type="url">
   <resource methods="POST GET OPTIONS DELETE PUT"
             url-mapping="/*"
             faultSequence="fault">
      <inSequence>
         <filter source="$ctx:AM_KEY_TYPE" regex="PRODUCTION">
            <then>
            <property name="Proxy-Authorization" expression="fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('userName:password'))" scope="transport"/>
            <property name="POST_TO_URI" value="true" scope="axis2"/>
               <send>
                  <endpoint name="admin--Hello_APIproductionEndpoint_0">
                     <http uri-template="http://echo.jsontest.com/key/value/one/two"/>
                  </endpoint>
               </send>
            </then>
            <else>
               <sequence key="_sandbox_key_error_"/>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </inSequence>
      <outSequence>
         <send/>
      </outSequence>
   </resource>
   <handlers>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.security.APIAuthenticationHandler"/>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.throttling.APIThrottleHandler">
         <property name="id" value="A"/>
         <property name="policyKey" value="gov:/apimgt/applicationdata/tiers.xml"/>
      </handler>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtUsageHandler"/>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.usage.publisher.APIMgtGoogleAnalyticsTrackingHandler">
         <property name="configKey" value="gov:/apimgt/statistics/ga-config.xml"/>
      </handler>
      <handler class="org.wso2.carbon.apimgt.gateway.handlers.ext.APIManagerExtensionHandler"/>
   </handlers>
</api>
```

Be sure to change the userName & password in the above `Proxy-Authorization` property.

Comment: it didnt work for me even after adding those credentials. On command line, after setting up proxy, if I use curl and make call to direct endpoint it works but not using API manager. Atleast that confirms that the credentials I have used are valid

Comment: This should work out of the box. May be you are doing something wrong. Can you attach your API Synapse XML?

Comment: it worked now.. looks like there is no whitespace after "Basic" and base-64 encoded credentials for proxy-authorization header. adding space to basic like this - fn:concat('Basic ', base64Encode('userName:password')) - worked. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah yes. Good catch. There should be a white space after "Basic". I have updated my answer.